# Why does the Community User reject / approve edits?

Tags: support, edits, community-user

I am sure this must have been asked quite a lot of times, but I am unable to find something about the guidelines the *Community* uses when approving / rejecting edits.

I just fixed a *first question* to be a bit more appealing, yet **[the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/229918)** was immediately rejected by the Community. I can live with that, but I was wondering what rules the Community user applies when looking at edits.

Any documents explaining that?

Comment: The suggested edit doesn't even appear in the revision history, and there was no edit by another user on the post, so it can't be that someone hit decline+improve.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First off, check the suggested edit itself. If there is *also* an **Edit** action by another user on the suggestion, then a user with 2,000 reputation clicked the **Improve** button on the suggestion and unticked the "this edit was helpful" checkbox, meaning he/she did not think the suggestion was good.

**However** that's not the case here, as no such user appears in the [revisions history of the post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9923703/revisions). (Fabian edited it now, not related to the suggestion at hand)

This means *five minutes grace period* case: if the OP of the post edits within five minutes, it's not logged anywhere - the last edit he/she made will appear as the initial post.

What happened is the following:

1. OP posted original question.
2. Less than one minute after that, he clicks the edit link.
3. One minute later you suggested your edit.
4. OP confirms his edit thus "kicking" your suggestion away - as part of the approve/reject/improve mechanism, when edit is made by other user it means "improve" which used to be just "approve and edit yourself" but recently we gained the ability to "reject and edit yourself" so I guess it became the default behavior.

Bug or by design? Not for me to decide. :)

Note: once edit was suggested, the post can't be edited (no "edit" link) so it means step 2 must come before step 3.

Comment: Is there something like a *bug by design*? Thanks for the explanation. One should not shoot too fast around here I guess.

Comment: It was already suggested to disable edits in the first five minutes (too lazy to search but sure it exist) anyway of course there is.. there is new design that cause bug. Welcome to the world of programming! ;)

Comment: It might be better (and less confusing) if in such cases the edit would not be marked as "rejected" but as "overwritten by simultaneous edit".

Comment: @tobias agreed, not up to me to decide though.