# What criteria does Community use for approving/rejecting edits?

Tags: discussion, community-user, rejected-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does the Community User reject / approve edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127375/why-does-the-community-user-reject-approve-edits)

I suggested [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/314481) and it was rejected by [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community). How does Community makes those decisions? I'm not particularly bothered, but I think the edit was valid. The content of the question wasn't altered, but the readability was (I feel) improved.

Comment: I actually approved a very similar edit, but by someone else: http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/314484

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Someone else had their own suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11454633/revisions), which apparently was more substantial than yours. Community "rejected" your edit because it wasn't accepted, not due to any quality criteria.

As this is merely a ["system message"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137611/suggested-edit-rejections-for-concurrent-edits-should-not-count-for-the-suggeste) in this case, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't worried, just curious. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

Community user doesn't reject, or approve suggested edits.

What generally happens is that a user improves the suggested edit, and then unselect the checkbox for "Suggested edit was helpful." If this is done, the suggested edit appears as rejected by the Community user; if the checkbox is left selected, as it is by default, then the suggested edit appears as approved from the Community user.

[image: screenshot]

This is done because, on Stack Overflow, two users are normally necessary to reject/approve a suggested edit.

Comment: This situation seems different as the other person (whose edit was eventually accepted) didn't have enough rep to vote on the OP's suggested edit.