# Removing good luck and other greetings from questions

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Editing posts that contain salutations or other edits that could be considered “minor”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140006/editing-posts-that-contain-salutations-or-other-edits-that-could-be-considered)

Sorry I'm sure this must have been asked already but I couldn't find anything in search (because the search terms appeared in irrelevant questions). Basically, someone was signing off on all his answers with a "Good Luck" and another user went through all of them and removed the Good Luck, triggering quite a few edits. Obviously it would have been better to not include it in the first place, but **is it bad enough to warrant the edits and at least 3 reviewers time to approve/reject?**

Examples:

> https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1434922
>   https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1434886
>   https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1434889
>   https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1434880
>   https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1434884
>   https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1434892

(There were more in this block, but from the IDs you can see how close they were to each other).

Comment: I would have rejected such a simple edit as "too minor". Which some have, but not enough.

Comment: The editor should have done more than just remove those lines. The edits are too minor. Bah, too many of these have been approved, this is rather depressing, really.

Comment: I think a sample page of 5-7 common editing situations and the appropriate actions would be useful.

Comment: I rejected all of those edits... but I notice that most of other reviewers are approving those edits, and the reputation of the user that removes "Good luck" is still increasing... I don't think it's correct....