# What are the rules that should be followed when editing someone else's question?

Tags: support, edits, community, rejected-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does the Community User reject / approve edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127375/why-does-the-community-user-reject-approve-edits)

I edited a question to add a tag, but the Community user rejected the edit, in whose profile I read

> I'm a background process that helps keep this site clean!

How does that work? I mean, what are the rules I should be following when editing so the Community user accepts the suggested edit?

Comment: OK. thanks, but what about community? i just added a valid tag. why would it refuse it?

Comment: That's going to be more tricky to figure. If you have a link to the suggested edit you made (dunno if these are available to lower reputation users like us) you could see what the reason was, other than that you could try [asking in a relevant chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) if you have more than 20 SO rep. Sometimes tags don't mean to be used for what the name tells you, perhaps the tag wiki or tag wiki excerpt tells more about its usage. But agreed, perhaps the reviewer wasn't right about it, you could always try to give it a second shot if you believe you're right...

Comment: I [found it](http://stackoverflow.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/652377) through your profile. I think what really happened here is that the community user (it's really a robot, not an user) thinks your edit is not substantial enough; there is this one thing about editing is that people expect you to look at the title and post as well, as to make the edit worth it and not have edits flood the activity stream. On other sites than SO on this network, you'll see the frontpage accts as a "latest additions / changes" page; if you edit 10 posts there in quick sucession you'll ring a bell.

Comment: Adding a tag does not need to be done via edits. You should see a link to the right of the tags called "edit tags" (you'll need to mouseover to see it) which should let you add a tag without needing to edit. This is why the edit is too minor. These should be rejected unless you did more to the post to improve it. Hope this helps!