# Why did Community user reject my edits?

Tags: discussion, edits, community-user, rejected-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does the Community User reject / approve edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127375/why-does-the-community-user-reject-approve-edits)

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1313346) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1325533) Community user rejected my edits in last few days. Could someone tell me why?

Comment: Actually, it didn't. It merely takes the blame. If someone improves your edit, but marks it as not helpful, it will show up as a community rejection. And I think there are several other scenarios where this might happen.