# What is the average for the Community User to reject valid suggested edits?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

**Please note: I am not here to question/argue about why my suggested edits have been rejected.**

I have been observing a lot of incorrect rejections by the [community user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) lately. In my case, there have been 7 such rejections within last 7 days - i.e. one incorrect rejection almost everyday. That could be because I have been quite active on editing the questions, I am not sure about that. I tried to find an existing question on Meta that addresses this, but could not.

I see a pattern in these rejections - I see an edit by another user around the same time, so I believe according to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127378/203113) the below is what was happening -

> **Usually** such thing means 2k+ member clicked the "Improve" link on the suggestion and unticked the "this edit was helpful" meaning he/she did not think the suggestion was good.

Looking at the numbers, I have a total of [106 suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1694962/chaithanya-m?tab=activity&sort=suggestions), of which I think 10 or 11 or were rejected by the Community User, of which again 8 of them are valid suggestions.

Below is the list of what I think are valid suggestions that were rejected by the Community User.

- [Yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1325048)
- [2 days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1319711)
- [Jan 12](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1319511)
- [Jan 11](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1313767)
- [Jan 10](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1313245)
- [Jan 10](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1307557)
- [Jan 8](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1295120)
- [Jan 3](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1274512)

Does this sound to be about a normal average incorrect rejections that we cannot avoid and have to live with, or is this high number more of a new development lately - or, may be something like a rare case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Doorknob has explained how edited rejected by the Community user come about](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/163767/155160), but to address your specific question...

There isn't really a metric for that for how many of such rejections are normal. The answer is "the normal number of rejections is as many rejections as are needed".

The best we can do is examine whether or not people reject edits as "correctly" as possible, but there will always be some mistakes in the process since humans are directly involved.

Now, mind you, an edit rejection cannot be undone, so if you find one that was rejected wrongly, the best thing to do is to make the edit again (and make sure you include a meaningful edit summary). If you notice that a particular type of edits keeps getting wrongly rejected by the same people, flag the post for moderator attention and leave the moderators a note. They can investigate further and contact the reviewers if needed to help educate them.

Answer (score 8):

Community will reject suggested edits when the post owner or someone with 2000+ rep makes an edit and the suggested edit is still being reviewed.

Example for your first valid suggested edit rejection:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14305257/revisions

Another example:

[image: https://i.imgbox.com/adlwAb0W.png]

Similarly:

[image: https://i.imgbox.com/acqDbYnu.png]

(My Freehand Red Circles are kind of subtle, there's not really much to freehand red circle around :P)
(For anyone who doesn't get that, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19775))

Comment: I am aware of what happens behind the scenes for community rejections. My question was more towards if this many rejections was considered normal.

Comment: +1, hand drawn circles and nice addition with the circular light. All this needs is [jagged edges and drop shadows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295414/how-to-open-a-file-in-eclipse-and-jump-to-a-specific-line/2296043#2296043) and you sir, will win the internet

Comment: -1 needs some lens flare.