# Why did community user reject this edit?

Tags: discussion, bug, edits, community-user, rejected-edits

I made the following edit whilst reviewing posts in the first posts review queue

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2417824

It was immediately rejected by [Community user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community), there has been no other edit made to this post, how did this happen?

This situation differs from those presented in the following two questions

> [Why does the Community♦ user approve and reject edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184992/why-does-the-community-user-approve-and-reject-edits)
>   [Why does the Community User reject / approve edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127375/why-does-the-community-user-reject-approve-edits)

It differs in the following ways

1. The edit was not rejected as a result of another user with higher reputation making an edit. (see **A user with full edit privileges saves an edit over yours** https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184993/209611)
2. The edit was not rejected as a result of the original poster making an edit of their own in within the five minute grace period. (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127378/209611)

Unless a human decided to reject the edit, without giving a reason, this looks very much like a defect

I just noticed, that since the time that the edit was originally rejected another user has made exactly the same edits that I made to the question. The difference here is that the community user did not reject those exact same edits and I must add that the edits were made later than the original edit, so it's not likely there was a concurrency issue

Comment: I made the later edits you're referring to after seeing your question here. So that does indeed not explain a collision rejection.