# Add more detail in Community♦'s About Me

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, community-user

The [Community♦'s profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community)'s "About Me" currently states:

> Hi, I'm not really a person.
>
> I'm a background process that helps keep this site clean!
>
> I do things like
>
> - Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention
> - Own community questions and answers so nobody gets unnecessary reputation from them
> - Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted
> - Own suggested edits from anonymous users

Can we add more detail in it? Such as:

> - Reject suggested edits which may involves edit conflict
> - Own Community Moderator Election

Link: [Why does the Community User reject / approve edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127375/224817), [February 2013 Community Moderator Election](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168992/224817)

Comment: The "Own Community Moderator Election" is too minor. As for "Reject suggested edits which may involves edit conflict" it might fit, but better explain it better in the rejection itself.

Comment: @AsheeshR Maybe "summon"? I can't find a better word. (I'm not a nature English user)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Own Community Moderator Election
- Reject suggested edits which may involves edit conflict
- Own tag wikis and privilege wikis
- Flag smelly stuff for moderators and/or 10k users
- Own certain meta posts
- Become the second acceptance vote on an edited suggested edit
- Own bounties from deleted users
- Lock and delete spam posts
- Lock migrated posts and rejected migrations
- Own FAQ and about wikis

...

If we're going to get *that* specific, then we can probably fill a page or two worth of Community functions.

A better fix would be to improve [the corresponding meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user) and link to it on the profile

Comment: How about a single line? *I am a Stack Exchange Ninja. I am everywhere, every second of every day.*

Comment: I was about to link to that meta post before realizing you already linked to it. Why don't you post this answer there?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek On it :) [done]

Comment: @Manishearth Just curious, who have privileges to edit Community♦'s profile?

Comment: @johnchen902 Mods do (we can copy to all SE accounts too), but I bet (a) We're not allowed to, and (b) it's better that a dev changes the text because we may break something.